# html select option auto time

Tags: html

```
<select id="day" name="day">
  <option selected="selected" value="today">To day</option>
  <option value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
  <option value="December19">December 19</option>
</select>
```

How to setup the auto time for December so then i don't have to do manually change it every day?

What i mean automate its like after today then tomorrow gonna show December 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with HTML alone.

You need to create the dropdown using JavaScript or a server side language like PHP, PERL, JSP, .NET (to name a few).

Using a programming language is such a manner will allow you to get the current date and construct the dropdown.

Comment: thx for answer can you give me some example how to do in PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="day" name="day">
  <option selected="selected" value="today">To day</option>
  <option value="Tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date('Fd' strtotime('+2 days')) ?>"><?php echo date('F d' strtotime('+2 days')) ?></option>
</select>
```